# change event not fired on return key

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox with a jquery change event tied to it.

```
$('#txtAccountNo').change(function(){
        $('label[for="txtAccountNo"]').append('<span class="support">loading...</span>')
    });
```

The event works when the textbox loses focus, ie the user clicks out of it with the mouse or uses the tab key. But when the return key is pressed the event is not fired. Can anybody help me resolve this please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is standard behaviour for the `change` event. If you want to capture each <kbd>Enter</kbd> press you need to use the `keypress` event:

```js
$('#txtAccountNo').on('change keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.type == 'change' || (e.type == 'keypress' && e.which == 13)) {
    $('label[for="txtAccountNo"]').append('<span class="support">loading...</span>')
  }
});
```

Comment: I'd add `&& !e.shiftKey` if you want the user to be able to make a new line

Comment: @soyuka it's a textbox, so it's not possible to add a new line.

Comment: My mistake, I saw textarea

Comment: The [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/) states: "The `event.which` property normalizes `event.keyCode` and `event.charCode`. It is recommended to watch `event.which` for keyboard key input." Thus, I think you could simplify your `(e.keyCode || e.which) == 13` to just `e.which == 13` without suffering any browser incompatability issues.

Comment: @AndrewWillems Just saw your reply, and thankfully this is now the case so I updated the answer to simplify the use of `e.which`

Answer (score 3):

As you've highlighted, the `change` event is only fired when a text input looses focus. You should bind to `keyup` instead:

```
$('#txtAccountNo').on('keyup', function() { 
    $('label[for="txtAccountNo"]').append('<span class="support">loading...</span>')
});
```

As a post-script to the above, it's probably a wise idea to also maintain the `change` event, as you'll likely also want to run the functionality when someone pastes text into the textbox. You can do that by using:

```
$('#txtAccountNo').on('keyup change', function() { ... });
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Comment: Thanks @Jimbo. Edited as appropriate.

Comment: @Jimbo do you have a source for that? `click()` is just a shortcut for `on('click', fn)` anyway.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in my original sample, I had used `bind()` not `keyup()`. See the jQuery docs > http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: @BenM ah, that explains it then :)

Comment: thanks, but this would not work for me. I need it to work on the enter key only, not any key, as i dont want the postback event fired on the asp.net side until the user deliberating changes the focus (by mouse, click, tab or return key).... my mistake i should have mentioned this in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in modern browsers, and jQuery (which appears to be being used in the question) higher that 1.7, the return button will commit the change without needing a lose focus, the code should work.

```
<input/><output/>
$("input").change( function() {
    $("output").val( $("input").val() );
})
```

Check out the simple test here:
http://jsfiddle.net/4vBSm/2/

This does not occur in IE 9 and lower though. (And jQuery is not going to fix that http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11556 )

Answer (score 1):

As noted in Matthew's answer, the problem occurs in IE9 and earlier, but not in modern browsers. I would suggest below solution, which will just add this feature to all browsers:

```
$('input[type=text]').on('keypress', function (e) {
    var $input = $(this);
    if (e.which == 13) { // Enter was hit
        $input.trigger('change');
    }
});
```

It listens to keypresses on text inputs and if <kbd>Enter</kbd> is hit, it fires a change event.

Comment: As far as my testing goes this approach induces a side-effect: Once the textbox loses indeed loses focus the change event gets fired again for no reason (ostensibly). Maybe a more appropriate approach would be to programmatically pass focus back and forth between two textboxes so that the change event will get triggered "naturally".