# How to change desired div's background color by entering hex color in input filed (with jQuery or without)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Want the background color of the 40x40px box automatically change by entering desired color in input field. I need both solutions, with jQuery and without (if it is possible).

I wrote some code, but got stuck when tried to bind entered value in input field with value of background color proprety in jQuery code...

**HTML code**

```html
<div>
   <span>Enter color (Hex Code):</span>
     <span> <input class="pickedColor" type="text"/> </span>                      
</div>
</br>
<div class="elementToChange" style="height:40px; width:40px; border:1px solid black"></div>
```

**jQuery code**

```js
$('.pickedColor').on('change', function() {
    $('.elementToChange').css('background-color' : 'some value');
})
```

Comment: Also, you might want to look into some input validation to handle the case when an incorrect color value is entered. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027423/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-hex-color-representation) could be a place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JQuery

you can use  `keyup` event:

```js
 $('.pickedColor').keyup(function() {
        $('.elementToChange').css('background-color', $(this).val());
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <span>Enter color (Hex Code):</span>
     <span> <input class="pickedColor" type="text"/> </span>                      
</div>
</br>
<div class="elementToChange" style="height:40px; width:40px; border:1px solid black"></div>
```

### Javascript

```html
<div>
   <span>Enter color (Hex Code):</span>
     <span> <input class="pickedColor" type="text" onkeyup="changeColor(this.className)"/> </span>                      
</div>
</br>
<div class="elementToChange" style="height:40px; width:40px; border:1px solid black"></div>
<script>
    function changeColor(className){
     document.getElementsByClassName("elementToChange")[0].style.background = document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0].value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery solution using keyup event did the work. I have no idea why the code with "on change" event doesn't work...

Comment: see this if you want to use onchange and avoid hitting on enter tab --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771023/change-event-not-fired-on-return-key

Answer (score 3):

This may help you :

```
 $('.pickedColor').on('change', function() {
        $('.elementToChange').css('background-color', $(this).val());
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, this should work.

```
$('.pickedColor').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('.elementToChange').css('background-color' : value);
});
```

Comment: It works after hiting Enter. Actually, what I wanted is to change div's color immediately after enternig hex color without hiting Enter.
keyup event did the work.

Answer (score 0):

### With Jquery

```
<div>
   <span>Enter color (Hex Code):</span>
     <span> <input class="pickedColor" id ="pickedColor" type="text"/> </span> 
     <span> <input id="pickedColorBtn" type="button"/> </span>             
</div>
```

its better if you let user to click and change button color

```
$("#pickedColorBtn").on("click",function(){
     $(".elementToChange").css('background-color', $("#pickedColor").val());
});
```

It is not possible without javascript or jquery as these language exists for user to interact with html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version without jQuery:

```
var j, lenJ, listenerTargets;

listenerTargets = document.getElementsByClassName('pickedColor');

function listener() {
    var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('elementToChange'),
        i, lenI;
    for (i = 0, lenI = targets.length; i < lenI; i++) {
        targets[i].style["background-color"] = this.value;
    }
}

for (j = 0, lenJ = listenerTargets.length; j < lenJ; j++) {
    listenerTargets[j].addEventListener('change', listener);
}
```

working Fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/oy7xwyxx/]

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#colorInput").focusout(function(){
 $('#divColor').css("background-color", $("#colorInput").val());
     });
});
```

```html
<div>
    <span>Enter color (Hex Code):</span>
    <span> <input type="text" id="colorInput"/> </span>                      
</div>
<div id="divColor" style="height:40px; width:40px; border:1px solid black"></div>
```